# QGIS Add dynamic text in layout from selected feature's attributes

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, dynamic-text

I have a layer called ERVEN with property details from which I select a property/ies. I create an automatic layout from a plugin.

In the layout, I need to add dynamic text. The text will be certain attributes/ values from the selected feature fields.

eg Township name from TOWNSHIP field and property number from PROPDESC field.

I don't know the expression to insert as label under item properties.

I think i need to use the is_selected but is not successful.

Comment: A layout from which plugin? What is automatic? An atlas?

Comment: I am using Search Layers plugin to pan to a selected feature using two fields' attributes. Then I use the Auto Layout tool plugin to make a map of the area. I need to have the attributes on which I searched (selected feature) as a Label/ text insert on the map. I don't want to manually type the attributes again in the map text box; I need an expression. I am not using Atlas, as it is on if and when basis. Not multiple pages at once. The layer on which do a search is a property layer with 700 000 entries, thus not for atlas/ map books.