# Create dynamic text in legend for visible Layer on map layout using SQL expression

Tags: qgis, sql, legend, expression, dynamic-text

QGIS 3.16

Looking to insert an expression to my layer, `Survey Coverage` (text), in the legend. I want dynamic text to reflect the attribute value from the field, `VIS_RADIUS` (Integer64) so it looks something like:

Survey Coverage (20 m)

---

Survey Coverage map layer id: `Spatial_SurveyCoverage_Mission`

Field: `VIS_RADIUS`

Map Item ID: `Working Map`

At present I have testing different expressions in the Legend Item Properties as follows:

```
Survey Coverage ([%to_string(display_expression(@Spatial_SurveyCoverage_Mission, "VIS_RADIUS"))%] m)

Survey Coverage ([%to_string(display_expression(@Spatial_SurveyCoverage_Mission, "VIS_RADIUS", map_get(item_variables('Working Map'), 'map_extent')))%] m)

Survey Coverage ([%layer_property('Survey Coverage', 'VIS_RADIUS')%] m)
```

**All result in...**

`Survey Coverage ( m)`

---

**Ultimate goal** is to reduce the amount of revisions to layouts for multi-map projects which I can share with colleagues to be more user-friendly.

---

*Edit*: Additional dynamic text using SQL to update as Map Extent is updated/moved

**Map Canvas**
[image]

**Map Layout Text Box Properties**

```
[% map_get(item_variables('Working Map'),'map_crs_description') %]
Base Map Source: ESRI World Topo
Map data sources from BC Gazetteer [%layer_property(@NTS, 'title')%] [%map_get(item_variables('Working Map'), 'map_layers')%]
[%attribute(get_feature('nts_snrc_50k', 'NTS_SNRC', 'IS NOT NULL'), 'NTS_SNRC')%]
[%@map_layers%]
```

As seen in the below image, the 'map_crs_description' reveals text in a way I want. However, the text after BC Gazetteer **does not appear** in the text box display.

[image]

---

*RE*: aggregate expression

Solution provided yields no result...

Survey Coverage Layer Properties > Variables

*note: the "display as" in Source is greyed out, unsure why or if it even effects this at all.*

[image]

Comment: FYI: similar dynamic challenges: [dynamic layout user expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/435790/qgis-dynamic-layout-user-expression-only-works-for-map-item) and [dynamic text with selected features attributes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429941/qgis-add-dynamic-text-in-layout-from-selected-features-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `aggregate` function for that, something like the expression

```
survey radius: [% aggregate( 'Survey Coverage', 'sum', "VIS_RADIUS")%] m
```

will get the aggregated sum of all values within the field VIS_RADIUS. If you want to limit it on the visible area in your Map, you can use the filter criteria of the aggregate function and intersect the geometries of the layer with the mapextent.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why, but entering this into the legend properties for that layer and into the text box does not work. I even tried setting it to the layer_id. Is `'Survey Coverage'` in your example here the **layer** or **layer_name** value? My 'Survey Coverage' only appears in **layer_name** (see edit above)

Comment: the aggregate takes the layer name like it is displayed in the layer tree. you can test the function anywhere, like in the normal expression window. when it works there it should work in the layout anyway. for some reasons, in the layout sometimes the aggregate shows no result. the I normaly test it in a second QGIS session with the same layer to be sure, that the expression is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your want to get only one specific information and not an aggregate like a sum or count. So here is two solution, only working **if you use atlas**.

### Solution 1

*Condition : your atlas coverage layer is your layer containing the field VIS_RADIUS.*

You can access attribute of your current atlas feature really easily. Here is the expression for your example :

```
attribute(@atlas_feature, 'VIS_RADIUS')
```

### Solution 2

*Condition : your atlas coverage layer share a common attribute with your layer Spatial_SurveyCoverage_Mission.*

I assume your atlas coverage layer has field named `survey_coverage_id` to connect with the field `id` of your layer Spatial_SurveyCoverage_Mission. For your layer Spatial_SurveyCoverage_Mission the id must be unique.

Here is the expression to get the value you want :

```
attribute(
 get_feature(
  'Spatial_SurveyCoverage_Mission',
  'id',
  attribute(@atlas_feature,'survey_coverage_id')
 )
,'VIS_RADIUS')
```

You can adapt your expression to your layer name and field name.

Comment: I will need to explore how to use the Atlas more, at a preliminary glance, I don't know if it will allow multiple atlas features to be created. Another goal is to have multiple dynamic text items that will update depending on which features are visible in the map layout (item id: 'Working Map'). Another example being NTS (50K) map layer to display  attribute value(s) (eg: 082L03) in the 'NTS_SNRC' field. Please let me know if this needs elaboration, I'll try uploading a screenshot if it helps.