# QGIS Dynamic Layout: User expression only works for Map Item

Tags: layouts, dynamic, qgis-expression

#### Problem Description

I have been trying to create a dynamic layout in QGIS, such that the only parameter changing is the scale, and page width, map width, scalebar position, etc. are determined automatically.
I am using the following expression to first find the lowest visible layer, of which I then extract the extent. Then I finally compute the layout size given the scale and extent.

```
(xmax(layer_property(array_last(array_filter( @layer_ids, is_layer_visible(@element) )), 'extent')) -
xmin(layer_property(array_last(array_filter( @layer_ids, is_layer_visible(@element) )), 'extent')))
* 1000 / round(@map_scale)
```

When using the expression on a `Map` Item, it works like a charm. But once I try to apply the same to the dimensions of the `Page`, the expression returns *NULL*. Similarly, for a `Scalebar` item, the expression fails to automatically return the correct coordinates. I have traced the error to the subexpression `array_filter( @layer_ids, is_layer_visible(@element))`, which returns an empty array.

#### Questions

Is this intended behavior due to some environment variables changing, and/or is there a fundamental misunderstanding of how expressions work in QGIS?
Is there a workaround to still achieve what I am trying to do?

Best, 
Colin